# python modules that I can read and click on a keyboard key except pynput

Tags: python-3.x, pynput

I'm looking for python modules that I can read and click on a keyboard key except pynput

because I want to create a script that allows me to select a specific button and hold it until I click esc, and pynput while working will slow down the reaction of other buttons after a while of work by up to 10 seconds

I even used pygame.time.Clock().tick(1) but it didn't work

Comment: A potential alternative could be the `PyAutoGUI` module. This is a module that allows you to automate the mouse and keyboard. It allows you to press, hold, and release any key on the keyboard. You can also use the module to detect the state of the keyboard and see if a certain key is being held down. This module should be able to provide you with what you need.

Comment: It sounds like you have a specific problem with your `pynput` implementation, you could include that code as a [mre] to a new question which might be more likely to be answered. For tips on crafting answerable questions, see [ask].

Comment: unfortunately, I change the code in all ways and there is almost nothing left of it, but in general it was like waiting for TAB and F12 to be pressed, then reading the pressed button and clicking it and starting a loop that reads whether ESC was pressed (pynput)

Comment: and as for pyautogui, I know it quite well and I didn't know that it can also read key clicks from the keyboard, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **keyboard**. Keyboard is a python module that allows you to detect and simulate key presses, as well as bind global events and hotkeys. As mentioned by @Mania, **pyautogui** is also a great module for this. Pyautogui allows control of the mouse and keyboard and can also locate images using PIL. Pyautogui *cannot*, however, detect key presses, and since you mentioned that you would like to detect key presses, that is why I think keyboard is also necessary (if you prefer not to use pynput).

To hold a key down until esc is pressed:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

pyautogui.keyDown('f') #I chose f but it can be anything (holds f down)
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'): #waits until esc is pressed
        break

pyautogui.keyUp('f') #releases the key f
```

You could also do it this way:

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

def release_key():
    pyautogui.keyUp('f') #releases the key f

keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', release_key()) #f held down until esc is pressed

pyautogui.keyDown('f') #I chose f but it can be anything (holds f down)
```

here, instead of using a while loop, you add a hotkey using keyboard, so whenever esc is pressed, it calls the function `release_key()`, and releases the key. This way, when using a hotkey, your python program can perform other tasks while still holding that key down until you press esc, instead of being stuck in a while loop. The reason I use pyautogui here is because I've seen plenty of problems with keyboard holding down keys. In fact, there are many stack overflow posts about keyboard not *holding* the key down. Pyautogui holds the key down without problems when I have tested it.

**Note:** When you run this code, unlike normally when a user simulates a key press and holds the key down, you will not see a bunch of f's being typed into the shell, like this: "fffffffffffffffffffff". Instead, only one f will probably be typed. This is **not** an error with pyautogui, the key is being held down. For some reason, the virtual key press doesn't allow the key to be typed repeatedly when it is held down. If you truly wanted that output: "ffffffffffffffffffffffff", you could just use the `pyautogui.write()` or `pyautogui.typewrite()` functions to get that output, although given your scenario, I don't think that is necessary.

Keyboard and pyautogui are great modules for this, although it is not ideal. Pynput can both control the keyboard as well as detect key presses, so that is the best module for this. As @import random suggested, it would help if you posted your code on pynput to help us understand why pynput didn't work for you. I would also recommend explaining the context of the code better, even posting a snippet can help. The more detail in your answer, the easier it is to understand.